# Getting value of x by differentiating a given equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If we consider an equation $x=2x^2,$ we find that the values of $x$ that solve this equation are $0$ and $1/2$. Now, if we differentiate this equation on both sides with respect to $x,$ we get $1=4x.$ Now, I know that it is wrong to say that the value of $x=1/4,$ but then, what does $x=1/4$ signify? Is it related to maxima or minima? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do $x = 0, 1/2$ signify in $x = 2x^{2}$? If you think of them in terms of roots of the polynomial $p(x) = 2x^2 - x$, then the roots of its derivative, namely $4x - 1$, will be, as you said, $x =1/4$. The roots of the derivative indicate the inflexion points of $p(x)$. We can see that $p(x)$ is decreasing from $x = 0$ up to $x = 1/4$, and then increases indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Given two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x),$ the solutions to the equation $f(x) = g(x)$ are precisely the roots of the polynomial $h(x) = f(x) - g(x),$ and the solutions to the equation $f'(x) = g'(x)$ are precisely the critical points of the polynomial $h'(x) = f'(x) - g'(x).$

Particularly, if $f(x)$ is a linear polynomial and $g(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial, then $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial, hence $h'(x)$ is a linear polynomial, and there is exactly one root of $h'(x).$ Consequently, there is only one critical point of $h(x),$ and this critical point corresponds to the global maximum (respectively, global minimum) if the leading coefficient of $h$ is positive (respectively, negative).